# Cassandra Database issue while im Insert into a new column

Tags: error-handling, cassandra, multiple-columns

I've just installed Cassandra database because as I saw it provides dynamically creating of new columns in a table without need to altering it
But when I make a dummy Insert like:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, name, age, description) VALUES (uuid(), 'John Doe', 25, 'Test');
```

where the mytable has id,name,age and it doesnt have description column it returns me error:

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Undefined column name description in table mykeyspace.mytable"
```

Isnt it supposed to dynamically make the description column inside the mytable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the existence of the `description` column, it won't auto-create it for you within `mytable`.

You could do,

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD description TEXT;
```

and your INSERTs with the `description` column will begin working again.

Answer (score 0):

> Isnt it supposed to dynamically make the description column inside the mytable?

No. It is a common misconception that Cassandra is "schemaless," when it does in fact require and enforce a schema. Originally, Apache Cassandra supported a schemaless key/value approach to data representation, but that hasn't been the case for several years now.

In your case, you will need to define your table similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE mykeyspace.mytable (
    id UUID,
    name TEXT,
    age INT,
    description TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Although truth be told, unless you plan on querying that data by `id` (a UUID), using a primary key definition of `PRIMARY KEY(name,id)` might be a better approach. That will allow querying by the `name` column, instead.